# Primary keys in a logging database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, logging, primary-key

I'm creating a database that is going to be logging PC usage. There will be several entries of the format: Computer, User, AuditTime. It is for keeping track of who was logged in to what computer at the time an audit was performed. Computer and User reference tables of all the computers and users in our company and their respective departments.

Should I make Computer and AuditTime together a composite key? Is there a performance hit or gain from bothering to specify a primary key when really, a unique constraint on this table is unnecessary?

The database is MS SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server makes your primary keys your clustering keys by default (unless you specifically tell it not to), and as Kimberly Tripp shows in her blog post [The Clustered Index Debate Continues](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx), having a clustered index on a table is beneficial for any operation - including INSERT and DELETE - as long as it's the *right* type of clustered index.

A good clustered index should be:

- narrow
- unique
- stable (no changing)
- ever increasing

The best fit would be a `INT IDENTITY` surrogate key - I would advise against compound indices for the vast majority of cases.

Comment: and consider a bigint if there's a chance of going beyond a couple billion rows...easier to do it up front than change it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will go with int since we will be clearing logs out that are over ~400 days old and that only puts us in the couple hundred thousands. Surrogate identity int it is.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: Vote for Marc_s!

There is a performance hit by having a primary key -- that's why they aren't generally configured in tables with high insertion, low reading use (IE: logs).  But a clustered key is good.

Comment: Not entirely true - the benefit of having a **clustered key** (and thus a clustered table vs. a heap) actually outperforms any downside of a PK

Comment: @marc_s: Thx - I default to Oracle, none of this clustered key nonsense :p

Comment: but REF CURSORS and stuff like that - instead of nice result sets - from stored proc..... to each system its "thorns" and "warts" :-)

Comment: @marc_s: Oracle packages > SQL Server assemblies, or stand-alone procs/functions by far.  And PLSQL syntax is *way* cleaner - TSQL feels like VB :p

Comment: It's been too long since I've seriously used Oracle - can't remember all the awful warts :)

Comment: @marc_s: I don't acknowledge much of Oracle before 9i, in my defense